# Bootstrap Glyphicons hiding border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

For some reason, glyphicons hide a border of a container if it's being floated. Can someone explain this, and if there's a known workaround?

[bootply.com/kmhAN31yEn](http://www.bootply.com/kmhAN31yEn)

[image: glyphicon bug]

OS X 10.11.1, Chrome 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit)

Comment: your bootply runs OK in FF42 win10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the display type of the glyphicon element to `display:inline;`but that might have a negative effect on your layout. If that's the case, apply the border to the floated div itself.